# Android app showing incorrect Spanish accent characters

Tags: android, internationalization

I have a current Android app that uses i18n via resources. res/values-es/strings.xml and so on. When I test it on a device with the language set to Espanol it pulls the correct resources, from the values-es file, but the accent characters are way out of whack.

For example, I want to use the lowercase o with an accent (ó). I have tried with the actual character in the strings.xml file (using the character map on Ubuntu to create the string) and with the entity, in either case it comes out like some other character set accent I don't recognize:

[image]

The same character looks perfect WITHIN strings.xml when using many different text editors. And the file is UTF-8 (tried recreating it with the Android "wizard" tool in Eclipse to make sure).

strings.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
            <string name="label_app_version">Versión</string>
    </resources>
```

Now I've used French, and German before in other Android apps, with all sorts of accents, and haven't seen this problem, so I'm entirely confused at the moment. What am I doing wrong this time?

Comment: I should also add that I've tried this on several different emulator instances, and on a real device. I get the same result as in the screenshot above (not the correct accent).

Comment: If you did "clean" then "build" to ensure that older resource files are regenerated (maybe after a file "refresh" in Eclipse to be sure) then I am afraid I am out of ideas.

Comment: I did do clean build and made sure it re-gened. Next I'm going to try a separate test project and use ant, and then work my way back from there. Thanks for responses though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved this one. I was using a font and calling setTypeface earlier in the code. The font I'm using must not have the special characters needed for the other languages. I need to check to make sure my user's are using a locale that my font supports before setting the font.

I should have realized this and checked it earlier.

So the bottom line is this, if you get strange results with certain characters in different locales, make sure you're not using fonts that don't support those characters. Fall back to not using a font (don't call setTypeface) and test that way.

Answer (score 3):

That diacritic is actually called a breve, common in many eastern european languages. I had the same problems before once. I even have a question here on SO. Since nobody solved the problem, it's worth the shot...

This isn't clear to me yet:

1. Does it happen only on this project? Did you try others? (maybe a project mistake)
2. Try including other language folders (try, say, values-fr). Do you have the same problem?
3. Did you try to build your app inside Eclipse? Did you try building manually on the command line?

Then, you could try:

1. Instead of the "ó" (here in PT we use the same), try `\u00f3`. Like: `Versi\u00f3n`. Do you get the proper latin small o with acute? Just to clear things.
2. Build your app using `ant` (`$ ant release`) manually on the command line. Report back the results.

This *may* help the guys here (who are much more experienced than I am) guess where the problem can be.

Best regards!

Comment: I didn't try other projects with this same string, but I'll make a test project and give it a shot. I did try adding values-fr, no difference. I haven't done a manual build yet, but will momentarily and will report back. I tried the u00f3n and even amp-pound-oactute and they all get the same "breve" result. I'm going to use ant and try a separate test project next. Thanks for the response though, gave me some ideas about trying different stuff.

Comment: So I made a test project using the default Android project setup with one Activity. I then added label_app_version to the strings.xml already created in the default res/values location, and made a res/value-es/strings.xml with the "Versiòn" and it works fine on the same emulator instance and devices where my app doesn't work with the same string. Odd. Must be something in the project, some setting, some way the resource is compiled. Not sure. I'll keep chasing it down.

Comment: Yeah, I've been there before. I'm more than welcome to help you isolate the problem somewhat. But, honestly, when it comes to this in Eclipse, I prefer to create a new project and copy everything over so to not lose hours (and mind), but I'll admit it's not elegant... but it's a minute-solution. :-) Still, this happened to me once or twice I think. Generally, I try not to mess with encodings much (I set UTF-8/Unix globally and inherit everything). I starred the question as I'm also interested in its outcome. Good luck!

Comment: I haven't had time to get back to this yet, but basically I am not 99% confident it's either a project setting, or the file encoding (even though I have set it manually in Eclipse as noted above, and I haven't opened the files in any other editor than emacs [on Ubuntu and OS X] or Eclipse). When I get back to this I plan to recreate the project and then copy over files until I can recreate the problem. A new project works fine, existing project can't parse special chars even though it has same settings, UTF-8.

Comment: About the 99% thing: not sure if you thought about that, but I guess you can always open an hex editor to *really* make sure they're UTF-8 sources (check the character codes). My educated guess is that some tool along the production chain is causing the problem, not the file itself. I say that because it wouldn't make sense to be the file when even the Unicode sequence (\u00f3) does not work (see your 1st comment). Actually, I'm as lost as you.

Comment: Hello, I run into this issue : when I let Eclispe builds a debug apk, it's fine, but when I tried to use 'ant debug' & 'ant release', I got an apk that cannot read the accented letters (breve and é or à). Any direction I should look at ? I am searching around the ant configuration right now

Answer (score 1):

Check how the actual strings.xml file is stored.

In the file tree in Eclipse, right-click on the strings.xml file and select properties.

You will get a properties dialog for the file.

If not selected already, select the "Resource" line in the left column.

Check the "Text file encoding" area at the bottom.
It maybe selected as "default" or a specific encoding such as "UTF-8" selected.

Select the UTF-8 option. Save file. Clean & Build project (to re-gen resources) and then see if any change[image]s.

See attached screenshot.

Suerte, Andrew

Comment: It was on "Default (determined from content: UTF-8)" and I changed it to other UTF-8, as noted here, and I get the same weird raised half semicircle (original question screen shot).

Answer (score 1):

This is strange as it should not cause a problem. Maybe you should try to embed string into CDATA section, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="label_app_version"><![CDATA[Versión]]></string>
</resources>
```